# Retrieve only a portion of an XML feed

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy XMLFeedSpider to parse a big XML feed(60MB) from a website, and i was just wondering if there is a way to retrieve only a portion of it instead of all 60MB because right now the RAM consumed is pretty high, maybe something to put in the link like:

"http://site/feed.xml?limit=10", i've searched if there is something similar to this but i haven't found anything.

Another option would be limit the items parsed by scrapy, but i don't know how to do that.Right now once the XMLFeedSpider parsed the whole document the bot will analyze only the first ten items, but i supposes that the whole feed will still be in the memory.
Have you any idea on how to improve the bot's performance , diminishing the RAM and CPU consumption? Thanks

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.XMLFeedSpider.iterator See this portion of the documentation. It describes the remedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are processing large xml documents and you don't want to load the whole thing in memory as DOM parsers do. You need to switch to a [SAX parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML).

> SAX parsers have some benefits over DOM-style parsers. A SAX parser
>   only needs to report each parsing event as it happens, and normally
>   discards almost all of that information once reported (it does,
>   however, keep some things, for example a list of all elements that
>   have not been closed yet, in order to catch later errors such as
>   end-tags in the wrong order). Thus, the minimum memory required for a
>   SAX parser is proportional to the maximum depth of the XML file (i.e.,
>   of the XML tree) and the maximum data involved in a single XML event
>   (such as the name and attributes of a single start-tag, or the content
>   of a processing instruction, etc.).

For a 60 MB XML document, this is likely to be very low compared to the requirments for creating a DOM. Most DOM based systems actually use at a much lower level to build up the tree.

In order to create make use of sax, subclass `xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator` and overrider `endElement`, `startElement` and `characters`. Then call `xml.sax.parse` with it. I am sorry I don't have a detailed example at hand to share with you, but I am sure you will find plenty online.

Comment: Thanks! I'll dive into it! That's what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the iterator mode of your XMLFeedSpider to `iternodes` (see [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)):

> It’s recommended to use the iternodes iterator for performance reasons

After doing so, you should be able to iterate over your feed and stop at any point.

Comment: I already use it, but parse_nodes will parse each item, so the whole 60MB feed will be parsed.Is there a way to decide how many nodes to read?