# Get start and end locations of each XML tags in python

Tags: python, xml, memory

I want to index a large(1GB) XML file. Therefore I need to get start and end memory locations of each XML tags, so that, later I want to randomly access each section of the file. Is there a method or a library for this? where can I file these information?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not geared towards providing tutorials. Please take the site tour and read links on what you can ask here. The best way to proceed for you is to search for the web for "xml processing in python". **I'm flagging this question for closing, as too broad.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only a portion of an XML feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919279/retrieve-only-a-portion-of-an-xml-feed)